# The highest power of $2$ dividing a polynomial evaluated at $x=3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, polynomials

Let $\nu_2(a)$ be the [$2$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of an integer $x$, i.e. the largest power $t$ such that $2^t$ divides $x$.

Define the operator $D=x\frac{d}{dx}$ and the polynomial $\Phi_k(x)=\frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}$. Observe that $D^n\Phi_k(x)$ is always a polynomial.

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true about the $2$-adic valuation of $D^{2n+1}\Phi_{16k}(3)$?
> $$\nu_2(D^{2n+1}\Phi_{16k}(3))=\nu_2(32k).$$

**Note.** For an alternative expression, one may take
$$D^{2n+1}\Phi_k(3)=\sum_{j=1}^k3^jj^{2n+1}.$$

**Remark.** I've changed the problem from my earlier post from $16k+8$ to $16k$ because this time there is a conjectured answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that for $r\geq 3$ we have that $$v_2\left(\sum_{j=1}^{2^r} 3^jj^{2n+1}\right)=r+1.$$
The case $r=3$ is an easy modular exercise. We will show that statement by induction Let $\displaystyle A_r= \sum_{j=1}^{2^r} 3^jj^{2n+1}$.
Then $$A_{r+1}=A_r+\sum_{j=1}^{2^r} 3^{j+2^r}(2^r+j)^{2n+1}=A_r+3^{2^r}\sum_{j=1}^{2^r} 3^j(j^{2n+1}+2^rj^{2n}(2n+1))+2^{r+3}B$$
using the binomial expansion for each term $(2^r+j)^{2n+1}$ and noting that for each $t\geq 2$, $rt\geq r+3$.
Let us observe that $3^{2^r} \equiv 2^{r+2}+1 \pmod{2^{r+3}}$ so
$$A_{r+1}\equiv 2(2^{r+1}+1)A_r+2^r\sum_{j=1}^{2^r} j^{2n}(2n+1)\pmod{2^{r+3}}$$ and all that is left to prove is that $\displaystyle 8|\sum_{j=1}^{2^r} j^{2n}$ for $r\geq 4$ which is trivial; $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ if $x$ is odd and for $n\geq 2$ every even term will have a factor of $16$. For $n=1$ just write the formula for $\sum j^2$.

Comment: Why it is enough to consider only $k=2^r$?

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{2^r(2m+1)} 3^j j^{2n+1} \equiv A_{r}+m A_{r+1} \pmod{2^{r+2}}$

Comment: For logical reasons and clarity it is better to show first $\sum_1^{2^r(2m+1)}\equiv A_r+mA_{r+1} \mod 2^{r+2}$ (your argument used for the inductive step $A_{r+1}$ applies). Then, you may say a similar reasoning works for the inductive step $A_{r+1}$. In that sense, I agree with Max's curiosity.

Comment: @VladMatei: please check again. The case $2^r$ for $r=3$ does not work.

Comment: Ok so let's do easy mods to convince you. $3^{2n+1}=3(8+1)^n\equiv 3(1+8n)\pmod{16}$, $5^{2n+1}=5(24+1)^n\equiv 5(24n+1)\pmod{16}$ and $7^{2n+1}=7\pmod{16}$. So we will be left to evaluate $3+3^4+3^5\cdot 5+3^7\cdot 7\pmod{16}$ which is zero.

Comment: @VladMatei: Thanks, indeed. But, I was meaning to say that evaluating the case of $k=2^3(2m+1)$ does not help get the answers from $k=2^3$. Do you agree? While such things work nicely (as you noted) for $k=2^r(2m+1)$ from $k=2^r$ when $r\geq4$. The same issues arise with the case $k=2m+1$ too.